# Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined) - when used with <component :is="comp">

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I have been stuck on this issue for a while with no information online.
using vue 3

- I define a layout component inside my router `meta:` tag.
- Inside my `App.vue` I check if a specified route has the layout meta tag, and if so the `component :is="layout" is true.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>

<script>
  computed: {
    layout() {
      let layout = null;
      for (const match of this.$route.matched)
        if (match.meta && match.meta.layout) layout = match.meta.layout;
      if (layout) return layout;
      return "div";
    },
}
</script>
```

router.vue

```
const usLayout = () => import("../layouts/usLayout.vue");

    {
      path: "/",
      name: "us",
      component: GenericRouterView,
      meta: { layout: usLayout },
      children: usRoutes,
    },
```

I get this error:

[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined) at `UsLayout` at `App`

And nothing is displayed on the screen. Any ideas what this error means / what causes it?

Answer (score 16):

I had this error when I migrated to `Vue3` and did not wrap my lazy loaded `Async Components` in the new helper function `defineAsyncComponent`.

Error

```js
const PdfViewer = () => import('@frontend/components/pdf-viewer.vue')
```

Works

```js
const PdfViewer = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@frontend/components/pdf-viewer.vue'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `div` in `is="div"`. The `:is` directive in `component` only accepts a component definition and not a tag.

With your code is not possible to have a direct render of the component as it is. You will have to wrap into another `div` or use `render` functions:

```js
<template>
  <div>
   <template v-if="layout === 'div'">
     <router-view />
   <template>
   <template v-else>
     <component :is="layout">
       <router-view />
     </component>
   </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  computed: {
    layout() {
      let layout = null;
      for (const match of this.$route.matched)
        if (match.meta && match.meta.layout) layout = match.meta.layout;
      if (layout) return layout;
      return "div";
    },
}
</script>
```

With render functions:

```
<script>
  computed: {
    layout() {
      let layout = null;
      for (const match of this.$route.matched)
        if (match.meta && match.meta.layout) layout = match.meta.layout;
      if (layout) return layout;
      return "div";
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(this.layout, [...])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I wraped the App.vue template in another div like sugessted. This now gives me a different warning `Component is missing template or render function at Anonymous key=1 at App`